# Base lambda function for closure not found

Tags: php

I'm working with new PHP framework (ofc u can smile :), and sometimes I catch very strange error:

> Base lambda function for closure not found
>   /application/modules/index/controllers/index.php#15

I think it's problem with APC extension (I found issue https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52144).

Simple example of pseudo **index.php**

```
<?php

// get meta information from many controllers
function getReflectionData() {
    $function_for_get_reflection = require 'controller.php'
}

// dispatch controller
function dispatch() {
    $function_to_call = require 'controller.php'
}

getReflectionData();
dispatch();
```

**controller.php**

```
<?php
return 
/**
 * @route /page/{$alias}.html
 */
function() { /*...*/ }
```

But I not understand how I can avoid this error if APC is enabled :(

Comment: You misspelled word `funciton getReflectionData()`

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: there can be no space after function in closures it must be `function(){` ..

Comment: I've been having this issue as well.  I just reload php with `service php5-fpm reload` and the issue corrects itself, but it is rather annoying to do every time I make a change.